# mysql query, optimisation, speed up

Tags: mysql

how optimisation mysql query?

Now I use Limit function, don't use *.

how else can I speed up the operation?

Thanks

Comment: both methods you're using has nothing to do with optimization

Comment: Not using `select *` can help can't it?  Probably not a lot but still...

Comment: It's not "optimization" but it is "speed up." I'm interpreting this more generally to be asking, "How can I get more quickly from transmitting a SQL statement to getting back results." Some of that is query optimization, but some of it is minimizing the amount of data being transferred.

Comment: can you provide the specific query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lolalola, you will probably get better responses if you provide your query for people to look at.

Without that the best I can do is direct you to mySQL's documentation on optimization:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html

You will probably get the most bang for your buck by reading up on the following:

- [Statement optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/statement-optimization.html)
- [Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: not only a query but rather a query along with EXPLAIN output, as well as CREATE TABLE output for all tables involved.

Answer (score 1):

To give you any specific advice, we'd need to see a specific query.

In general, the rules are simple:

1. Select only what you need (no extra columns, no extra rows), including when `JOIN`ing
2. Create an `INDEX` on columns (or combinations of columns) that you're likely to use often, especially those you're using to filter results.

Optimizing a specific query will often involve subtle changes to grouping, joins, conditions, fields, and ultimately every part of the query, but of course that sort of attention requires having a specific query to work with.